# Call external function from within class that accesses private properties

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to make my code a little drier by doing the follow in PHP:

```
function accessor($obj, $property) {
  return $obj->$property;
}

class SomeClass {
  private $variable;

  function variable() {
    return accessor($this, 'variable');
  }
}

$some = new SomeClass;
echo $some->variable();
```

The above code throws an error because the external function can't access the private variable. The code is simplified, further coding would make it more useful.

I'm not sure if this is possible but it would sure be nice!

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried the code yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want are traits (PHP 5.4+)- they are practically pasted into their parent classes, so they can access private state:

```
trait VariableThingy {
    function accessor($property) {
      return $this->$property;
    }

}

class Test {
    use VariableThingy;

    private $variable = 15;

    function variable() {
        return $this->accessor("variable");
    }
}
```

But no, it's not nice. It's atrocious. And the whole code is rather pointless. If you want dry, just go with a public variable. *DRY* and *encapsulated* are usually mutually exclusive.

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Thanks. I will actually be making it much more complicated. But people on SO always request that the questioner make the code simple, hence it is simple so it can be easily answered like you did it, but the code will appear pointless. Thanks again!